# Can a enum contain bools and strings if so how do I change the values?

Tags: c#, string, enums, boolean

I am making a DLL now I am trying to make a enum with bools and strings
But I want to be able to change the values of these bools and strings.

This is what I got so far :

```
public class boolAttribute : Attribute
{
    public boolAttribute(bool val)
    {
        isLoggedIn = val;
    }

    public bool isLoggedIn
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class stringAttribute : Attribute
{
    public stringAttribute(string val)
    {
        userFileName = val;
    }

    public string userFileName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public enum loginStatus
{
    [boolAttribute(true)]
    isLoggedIn,
    [stringAttribute(null)]
    userFileName,
}
```

I tried to change the value's in another class :

```
loginStatus.isLoggedIn = true;
loginStatus.userFileName = fileName;
```

This code ^^ is highlighted red saying :
the left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable property or indexer

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I tried to change the values in another class:                            loginStatus.isLoggedIn = true;
    loginStatus.userFileName = fileName;

Comment: Please clarify/confirm: You want to change those values at runtime?

Comment: I want to change them on runtime yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh stupid **FaceSlap**, sorry guys I think I have a better way :P

I changed the code to this :

```
public class loginStatus : Functions
{
    public static bool isLoggedIn = false;
    public static string userFileName = "";
}
```